# Delete nodes from returned from response.content using deserialization in RestSharp

Tags: c#, xml, restsharp

I know the Response.Content from my GET RestRequest is xml UTF-8. However I want to delete unwanted child nodes from the response.content. I can't assign the response to an xml document (because it returns a string apparently ?)  which I could use system.xml to delete unwanted child nodes.

I have a situation (below) where if I have three space_reservation nodes [1401, 1402, and 1401 & 1402], I want to delete the space_reservation nodes for MH-1402 and (MH1401 & MH-1402), and keep the space_reservation node for MH-1401. I want to do this before I use the a REST API to schedule the rooms because these room will present a duplicate schedule situation.

Here is the example of the response.content from the request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<r25:reservations xmls:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance">    
<r25:reservation xl:href="reservation.xml?rsrv_id=731397">
<r25:reservation_id>7313</r25:reservation_id>
<r25:reservation_state>1</r25:reservation_state>
<r25:event_start_dt>2016-04-12T09:00:00-07:00</r25:event_start_dt>
<r25:event_end_dt>2016-04-12T12:00:00-07:00</r25:event_end_dt>
<r25:event_id xl:href="event.xml?event_id=197559">197559</r25:event_id>
<r25:event_locator>2016-ABAHZP</r25:event_locator>
<r25:event_name>Spring Grand Rounds</r25:event_name>
<r25:event_type_name>Department Meetings & Events</r25:event_type_name>
<r25:organization_name>Sciences</r25:organization_name>
<r25:profile_name>April 12th Capture</r25:profile_name>
<r25:space_reservation xl:href="space.xml?space_id=335">
<r25:space_name>MH-1401</r25:space_name>
<r25:space_id>335</r25:space_id>
<r25:space_instruction_id>94367</r25:space_instruction_id>
</r25:space_reservation>
<r25:space_reservation xl:href="space.xml?space_id=336">
<r25:space_name>MH-1402</r25:space_name>
<r25:space_id>336</r25:space_id>
<r25:space_instruction_id>94368</r25:space_instruction_id>
</r25:space_reservation>
<r25:space_reservation xl:href="space.xml?space_id=337">
<r25:space_name>MH-1401 & 1402</r25:space_name>
<r25:space_id>337</r25:space_id>
<r25:space_instruction_id>94366</r25:space_instruction_id>
</r25:space_reservation>
<r25:resource_reservation xl:href="resource.xml?resource_id=55">
<r25:resource_id>55</r25:resource_id>
<r25:resource_name>Live plus on-demand</r25:resource_name>
<r25:resource_count>1</r25:resource_count>
<r25:resource_instruction_id/>
<r25:resource_instructions/>
</r25:resource_reservation>
</r25:reservation>
</r25:reservations>
```

Here are my deserialization classes:

```
public class Mreservation : List<reservation> { }

public class reservation
{

    public string event_name { get; set; }
    public DateTime reservation_start_dt { get; set; }
    public DateTime reservation_end_dt { get; set; }
    public DateTime event_start_dt { get; set; }
    public DateTime event_end_dt { get; set; }
    public string event_locator { get; set; }
    public int organization_id { get; set; }
    public List<space_reservation> spaceNodes { get; set; }
    public List<resource_reservation> resourceNodes { get; set; }
}

public class reservations
{
    public string pubdate { get; set; }
    public List<reservation> ReservationNodes { get; set; }
}

public class space_reservation
{
    public string space_name { get; set; }
    public int space_id { get; set; }
}

public class resource_reservation
{
    public int resource_id { get; set; }
    public string resource_name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code I have for eliminating nodes that have title 1401. I save to xml so I can confirm that the node has been deleted but still the same.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RestSharp;
using System.Xml;

namespace EliminateDuplicates
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var R25Client = R25_Rest_Login.R25Login();
        String testDate = new DateTime(2016, 4, 12).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        var CaptureRequest = new RestRequest("reservations.xml",    Method.GET);
        CaptureRequest.AddParameter("resource_query_id", "35304");
        CaptureRequest.AddParameter("start_dt", testDate);
        CaptureRequest.AddParameter("end_dt", testDate);
        CaptureRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
        var CaptureResponse = R25Client.Execute<Mreservation>(CaptureRequest);
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.LoadXml(CaptureResponse.Content);
        xdoc.Save("beforeRemoval.xml");
        foreach (var x in CaptureResponse.Data)
        {
            if ((x.spaceNodes[0].space_id == 335) && (x.spaceNodes[1].space_id == 336) && (x.spaceNodes[2].space_id == 337))
            {
                x.spaceNodes.RemoveAll(i => i.space_id == 335);
            }
        }
        XmlDocument xdocA = new XmlDocument();
        xdocA.LoadXml(CaptureResponse.Content);
        xdocA.Save("afterRemoval.xml");
    }
}
```

}

Im looking for the proper way to delete these nodes using RestSharp ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way of transforming structure of responses in RestSharp would be implementing a custom `IDeserializer`.

However, it seems you want to apply [business logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic) (i.e. remove some reservations) instead of just deserializing. In that case, you should use the already-deserialized object as shown in the example below.

```cs
var reservations = client.Execute<Mreservation>(request).Data;
foreach(var reservation in reservations)
{
    reservation.SpaceNodes.RemoveAll((space) => someCondition(space));
}
// ...go on using reservations
```

Comment: Here is what I tried, but did not work in trying to remove all of the spaceNodes except the nodes containing 1401+1402:                                                    `foreach (var x in CaptureResponse.Data)
            {
                if(x.spaceNodes[2].space_id == 337)
                {
                    x.spaceNodes.RemoveAll((space)x.spaceNodes[0].space_id == 335(space));
                }
                
            }`

Comment: The syntax of your [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) being passed to `RemoveAll` is wrong. You'll find examples in the [method's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi Panjan -- I am using `x.spaceNodes.RemoveAll(i => i.space_id == 335);` ; I did review all documentation you referenced.Getting closer but still not there yet..

Comment: Hello, that last portion of code looks fine. If you still get an error, please provide a full code example and the error message.

Comment: Hi Panjan, I've edited the original message to show all of the code (included parent node "reservations"), and main() -- There is no error message, but the beforeRemoval.xml and afterRemoval.xml are the same, so it doesn't appear to be removing the node that I want removed.

Comment: That's because you are modifying `CaptureResponse.Data` but making the XML file from `CaptureResponse.Content`. So do you want to save the response to an XML file or is it just a way of debugging the example?

Comment: I was just trying to see that the change was made -- but I can see via debugging with (F11) that is is working !

Comment: Glad it's working. Please accept the answer if you think it solved your problem.

Comment: Hi @Panjan - I'm revisiting this as I had to make a function using method overloading because I am now using this logic to delete one, sometimes two. nodes.

Comment: Hi @ProgrammerBret, I'm glad the answer is still useful after all the time. Please create a separate question if there is a follow-up. I'll help if I can. ;-)